# F# code works fine in REPL but gives stack overflow during compile

Tags: linux, f#, mono, stack-overflow

I would like to know if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong. I am running F# in mono/linux, the following code crashes giving me a stack overflow without any stack trace.

```
let rec gcd a b =
    match b with
       | x when x = 0 -> a
       | _ -> gcd b (a%b)

let z = (gcd 12 3)

printfn "%A" z
```

this works fine when I run the same code in the REPL.

Interestingly enough this works fine

```
let rec gcd a b =
    match b with
       | x when x = 0 -> a
       | _ -> gcd b (a%b)

printfn "%A" (gcd 12 3)
```

**EDIT:**

Trying the --optimize solution doesn't help, interestingly I found that following John Palmer's advice and replacing `x when x = 0` with just `0` worked, however when trying the same technique with `int64`, `0L` again gives me the same stack overflow. I don't see how this is a tail optimization problem since 3 is a factor of 12 the stack depth is low. I am putting this down as a bug unless someone else can enlighten me what is happening here.

Comment: Have you tried decompiling to see what the difference is?

Comment: no, how do i do that?

Comment: There are lots of free tools to do it.  Just search for ".net decompiler" and you'll have several options on the first page of search results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the fsi often is set up to use `--optimize` (definitely on windows from within Visual Studio, not sure about on mono).

As a result, the REPL will apply tail calls, but an unoptimized compiled app won't.  You can probably fix this by compiling with `fsharpc --optimize+ ...`

also, change

```
|x when x = 0
```

to

```
|0
```

EDIT: I think this might actually be a compiler / mono bug - adding a printf anywhere gets rid of it.

Decompiled versions:

bug:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.1 
IL_0001:  brtrue.s IL_0005
IL_0003:  ldarg.0 
IL_0004:  ret 
IL_0005:  ldarg.1 
IL_0006:  ldarg.0 
IL_0007:  ldarg.1 
IL_0008:  rem 
IL_0009:  starg.s 1
IL_000b:  starg.s 0
IL_000d:  br.s IL_0000
```

and good:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.1 
IL_0001:  switch (
  IL_0014)
IL_000a:  ldarg.1 
IL_000b:  ldarg.0 
IL_000c:  ldarg.1 
IL_000d:  rem 
IL_000e:  starg.s 1
IL_0010:  starg.s 0
IL_0012:  br.s IL_0000

IL_0014:  ldarg.0 
IL_0015:  ret
```

Nothing that seems weird to me.

I am running mono 3.2.8 and a reasonably modern F# compiler - I will test on latest git when I have time to recompile the compiler.

Comment: making the last change worked without any optimization. Do you know why that is? I don't see how tail optimization would be the problem here, the stack depth is not exactly high in any case.

Comment: @happygilmore - I am now reasonably sure this is a bug